# How to extract content from. Pst file using apache tika?

Tags: pst

How to parse.Pst file using apache tika
1.2?
How can I get entire body,  attachment, and all Metadata of email while searching with ljcene?

```
for (File file : docs.listFiles()) {
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

try {
parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);
}
catch (TikaException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (SAXException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Ya I have tried with autodetect parser with BodyContenthandle, Metadata and document object

Comment: for (File file : docs.listFiles()) {

Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();

ParseContext context = new ParseContext();

Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();

InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

   try {

    parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context);

   }

   catch (TikaException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

   } catch (SAXException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

   }

Answer (score 1):

If you're stuck with 1.2, you might try the recommendation [here](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/RecursiveMetadata)

If you're able to upgrade, we added that as the RecursiveParserWrapper in 1.7 ...just upgrade to 1.12 if you can, or wait a week or two and 1.13 should be out.

Via commandline:

java -jar tika-app.jar -J -t -i input_directory -o output_directory

Or in code:

```
    Parser p = new AutoDetectParser();
    RecursiveParserWrapper wrapper = new RecursiveParserWrapper(p,
            new BasicContentHandlerFactory(   
                   BasicContentHandlerFactory.HANDLER_TYPE.XML, -1));

    try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(file)) {
        wrapper.parse(is, new DefaultHandler(), new Metadata(), context);
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (Metadata metadata : wrapper.getMetadata()) {
        for (String name : metadata.names()) {
            for (String value : metadata.getValues(name)) {
                 System.out.println(i + " " + name +": " + value);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Tim! Don't forget that you can [follow this StackExchange filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/212512/apache-tika-questions) to get notified of new Tika questions at a frequency of your choosing! :)

Comment: I have tried this it gives only Metadata of mail, how can we retrieve the email body.... And attachments

Comment: Each metadata object represents a file/attachment.  How big is the list returned by 'wrapper.getMetadata()'? The content should be coming through in the 'X-TIKA:content key'.  I just double checked this on a freshly made PST, and it works.  Any chance you could share your PST with us on our [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/tika/)?

Comment: Thanks it's working, now how can I store this to the document object and store it in lucene index for indexing

Comment: That's more of a Lucene question and a design question, but it should be straightforward to pull the info out of the list of Metadata objects, populate a Lucene document for each logical document and add it to the IndexWriter.  If you are using Solr, see: https://lucidworks.com/blog/2012/02/14/indexing-with-solrj/